# CSS and Dynamic Content

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, handlebars.js

UPDATE: Messed up with my CSS, as nothing to do with dynamic content.!
**The answer is very informative though!**

I'm creating tags and inserting content with handlebars:

Handlebars code:

```
{{#each docs}}
    <article class="first"> 
        <p class="date">
            {{@date}} {{date}} 
        </p>
        <h4 class="header">{{@venue.title}} {{venue.title}}
        - {{@venue.city}} {{venue.city}}</h4>
        <p class="details">
            {{@description}} {{description}}
        </p>
    </article>
{{/each}}
```

If I just list articles, the CSS works - but when I let handlebars dynamically create them, it won't apply.

CSS code:

```
div.gig-items{
    article: nth-of-type(n +2); 
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Is there a way to first create the content and then apply CSS or some more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS is applied automatically at each repaint. So inserting your code in the source html or dynamically with js doesn't matter, the css will be applied correctly.

The problem come for sure from your code which has several errors...

First the CSS

- You want to style every `div` elements with class `gig-items`, but
  there is no `div` and no class `gig-items` in your template...
- You define a property `article` with value `nth-of-type(n+2)`, but this is not a property, this is a selector

you should use it like :

```
article:nth-of-type(n+2) {
  color: blue;
}
```

Then in your handlebar template :

- I assume you want to insert values by their names, but you use the
  prefix `@` which is reserved for handlebar's loop values like
  `@index` or `@keys`
- Another error is that you write double handlebar
  block to display the value. One is enough.

The correct way to insert value is :

```
<p class="date">{{date}}</p>
```